# How to load and edit a txt from a web page?

Tags: php, html, symfony

I need to open and edit a .txt from a web page with symfony. I have tried everything but the most I have managed is to open an external text editor and show the contents of the file there. But this causes that while the editor is open the response time of the page is counting and if it takes me more than 30 seconds to edit gives me an error of execution time.

This is the code with which the editor with the file:

```
/**
 * @Route("/exeBlack", name="exeBlack", methods="GET|POST")
 */
public function exeBlack()
{        
    chdir("c:\WINDOWS");
    exec('notepad.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\sgisi-master\public\archivo\UNAHBlacklist\Blacklist.txt');
    return $this->render('Default/dashboard.html.twig');
}
```

This code is in the controller and I call it from a button.

How can I make the page finish rendering and it does not matter that the text editor is running and does not keep counting the response time?

Comment: Why don't you open txt file in a textarea (read file content and show it in a textarea element) and then write it to the same file?

Comment: You can't. And this would only ever work at all when running the browser on the same machine as the server... otherwise the editor would open on the server and the user would see nothing at all. If you want to edit the file via the web application then load it into a text area within a form. When the form is submitted, save the new version of the text back into the file. Note of course that you can only edit files on the server. A web app does not have permission to save files into the user's disk, although you can offer them to be downloaded

Comment: I have tried countless times but I can not load the file in a textarea, I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Did you try to google "load the file in a textarea" ?

Comment: What you do is you load the contents of the file into a variable and then echo a textarea with the variable as the contents. Something like `$data = file_get_contents("somefile.txt");
echo '<textarea>' . htmlspecialchars($data). '</textarea>';` . Pretty sure you could figure that out with a little bit of thought and simple research.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps [`passthru()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) will better fit your requirements.

Also if you read carefully [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for `exec` function, you can see first comment suggesting multiplatform solution:

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

and lot of other code examples.

But actually your task looks as example of very bad practice. I suppose you need it only for studying/testing purposes and not going to use in production.